# Reverse animation in AnimatedVectorDrawable

Tags: android, animation, android-vectordrawable

Is that possible to play the animation in reverse order for AnimatedVectorDrawable?

Comment: I believe you need to make your own reverse animation. I don't think Android has a function that lets you do it.

Comment: @Stardust you are right. I implemented two separate animations.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into AnimatedVectorDrawable source code, you will find the method

```
/**
 * Reverses ongoing animations or starts pending animations in reverse.
 * <p>
 * NOTE: Only works if all animations support reverse. Otherwise, this will
 * do nothing.
 * @hide
 */
public void reverse()
```

You can call this method using reflection. For example like this:

```
    private boolean mAnimationReversed = false;

    public void startAnimation() {
        if(mAnimationReversed) {
            try {
                Method reverse = mDrawable.getClass().getMethod("reverse");
                reverse.invoke(mDrawable);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException| NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        mDrawable.start();
        mAnimationReversed = !mAnimationReversed;
    }
```

Just verified: works on API21, but does not work on API24 :-(

Comment: The `reverse();` method no longer exists in API24